# Error in Entity Framework 6.1 - modelBuilder.Build

Tags: entity-framework-6

I have been unsuccessfully trying to track down the follwoing error message:

`modelBuilder.Build (Database.Connection)
'modelBuilder.Build (Database.Connection)' löste eine Ausnahme des Typs 'System.ArgumentNullException' aus
    Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
    HResult: -2147467261
    HelpLink: null
    InnerException: null
    Message: "Der Wert darf nicht NULL sein.\r\nParametername: entitySet"
    ParamName: "entitySet"
    Source: "EntityFramework"
    StackTrace: "   bei System.Data.Entity.Utilities.Check.NotNull[T](T value, String parameterName)\r\n   bei System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.EntitySetMapping..ctor(EntitySet entitySet, EntityContainerMapping containerMapping)\r\n   bei System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.DbDatabaseMappingExtensions.AddEntitySetMapping(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, EntitySet entitySet)\r\n   bei System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.TableMappingGenerator.Generate(EntityType entityType, DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping)\r\n   bei System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.DatabaseMappingGenerator.GenerateEntityTypes(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping)\r\n   bei System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.Services.DatabaseMappingGenerator.Generate(EdmModel conceptualModel)\r\n   bei System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)\r\n   bei System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)"
    TargetSite: {T NotNull[T](T, System.String)}`

Can somebody give me a hint where to search for the cause? The validation of the model runs without errors.

That be super!
Thank you!
mph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was caused by a malformed configuration which threw an exception which was corrupted while bubbling up and some information - the important part - was lost.

I had to debug deep into EF's bally to find the issue.

In this case it was the mix of wrong configured mappings and automatic detection of relationships.